# Why I can't access Kivy lang property from __init__?

Tags: python, properties, attributes, kivy

I'm python beginner.
I enjoy to get the concept of Kivy and Python.
I don't understand why following code makes error.

Python-file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button


class MyButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        print(f"self.name is{self.name}") #it makes error.

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name) #But it doesn't make error!!


class TestApp(App):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TestApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.title = 'Test'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Kivy-file

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<MyButton>:
    name: "MyButton"
    on_press: self.print_name()

MyButton:
    text: self.name
```

I think name property is already exists because it is created as a class attribute in kivy file, and so the print_name method makes no error.

Where in the sentence was an error?
How can I use name property(attribute) made in kivy-file in the **init** method?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access that property in the `__init__()` method because the property is not yet created or set at that time. The property gets created and set when the `<MyButton>:` rule is evaluated in your `kv`. You can access the `name` property by delaying that access slightly. For example, by using `Clock.schedule_once()`:

```
class MyButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # print(f"self.name is{self.name}")  # it makes error.
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.print_name())

    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)  # But it doesn't make error!!
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!! But I want to know when the kivy rule is evaluated and the order. Please tell me the reference if you know that.

Comment: In general, when you call the `run()` method of the `App`, the `kv` file is loaded (if named correctly). The loading of the `kv` builds any root widget specified (which calls its `__init__()` method) and then applies any rules (specified by `<>` in the `kv`) appropriate for that widget..